# Singleton Class can't set property

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, singleton

```
main.m
  ... 
-(id) init{
     [[Singleton sharedSingleton] set_player:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"player.png"]]; 
...
```

This throws a bad access error every time.  How do I fix this?

Singleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#imzort "cocos2d.h"

@interface Singleton : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_enemies;
    NSMutableArray *_projectiles;
    NSMutableArray *_enemyProjectiles;
    NSMutableArray *_enemyProjectilesToDelete;
    NSMutableArray *_projectilesToDelete;
    CGSize _winSize;
    CCSprite *_player;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *_enemies;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *_projectiles;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *_enemyProjectiles;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *_enemyProjectilesToDelete ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *_projectilesToDelete;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite *_player;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize _winSize;
+(Singleton *)sharedSingleton; 
@end
```

Singleton.m

```
#import "Singleton.h"


@implementation Singleton
@synthesize _enemies,_projectiles,_enemyProjectiles,_enemyProjectilesToDelete,_projectilesToDelete,_winSize, _player;

+(Singleton *)sharedSingleton{
    static Singleton *_sharedSingleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedSingleton = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedSingleton;
}
-(id)init{
    if(self = [super init]){
        _enemies = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        _projectiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        _projectilesToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        _enemyProjectiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        _enemyProjectilesToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        _winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        _player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"player.png"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I can't find an error code, but in CCNode.m, xcode breaks at:

```
[_children makeObjectesPerformSelector:@selector(onEnter)];
```

With the error of EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

EDIT: 
Changing 
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CCSprite *_player;

to
    @property (nonatomic, assign) CCSprite *_player;

fixes the issue, but I don't know if that solution is really a 'singleton' solution.

Comment: You need to show your complete implementation alongwith crash log.

Comment: I've updated my original post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Am I trying to set the property of my Singleton class properly?  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, _children is from CCNode, it's a cocos2d class.